Exception when trying to receive email containing special characters using EWS from Java app
We have implemented an automated processor app which is consuming and processing incomming mails from a mailbox on exchange server (ver 2016). For receiving and processing of emails we are using EWS interface and EWS Java library (ver 2.0) in our Java app (running on Java 17). Recently we run into a problem when we got received emails containing special characters such as SOH (ASCII 01), STX (ASCII 02) resulting in the following exception:
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.local.ServiceObjectPropertyException: This property was requested, but it wasn't returned by the server.
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.PropertyBag.getPropertyValueOrException(PropertyBag.java:346)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.PropertyBag.getObjectFromPropertyDefinition(PropertyBag.java:760)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.getDateTimeReceived(Item.java:669)

When we manually replace just these special characters and resend the email to the mailbox then processing of the email works fine.
Our code looks like this:
itemPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
itemPropertySet.setRequestedBodyType(BodyType.Text);

...

Folder folder = findFolder(queueId);
ItemView view = new ItemView (MESSAGE_VIEW_SIZE);
view.setPropertySet(itemPropertySet);
view.getOrderBy().add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(folder.getId(), view);
messageIterator = findResults.getItems().iterator();

...

while (messageIterator.hasNext()) {
                Item item = messageIterator.next();
                if (item instanceof EmailMessage) {
                    EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)item;

                    try {
                        // Load message content
                        emailMessage.load(itemPropertySet);
                        String body = emailMessage.getBody().toString();
                        final String sender = emailMessage.getSender().getAddress();
                        //Further processing of email body

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                           log.error(e.getMessage());
                    }
               }
}

Any help would be very much appreciated as we are a bit stuck on this. :-)

Could you include the full stacktrace?
